# SSAS ProcessAdd on dimension using AMO

Tags: c#, ssas

Has anyone managed to get **ProcessAdd** working on a SSAS dimension using AMO?

There are a couple of examples kicking around for processing a partition, but as I understand for a dimension I have to declare an out-of-line datasourceview.

My dimension only has a single table.

Comment: hi, were you luck to solve this issue? I know it was long ago :)

Comment: @almazini I did solve it, but using the xml way of issuing commands (XMLA) instead of the AMO object model. It worked an absolute treat, and allowed us to perform intraday adjustments within seconds on a cube where a full reprocess took hours.

Comment: could you check my question? Maybe you will be able to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286842/amo-olap-querybinding?noredirect=1#comment89552187_51286842

Comment: or maybe you could post answer here in this post... it would help me and other people who met the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the DSV to use a view against the table (Just 'SELECT * FROM Table'), then configure the code below as per your needs (However you identify new rows, becomes the WHERE clause):

```
QueryBinding queryBinding = (QueryBinding)dimension.Source;
queryBinding.QueryDefinition += " WHERE (AuditKey = " + AuditKey + ")";                    
dimension.Process(ProcessType.ProcessAdd, queryBinding);
```

Note that I haven't tried this, I do ProcessAdd for partitions but haven't tried it with dimensions, but judging from the MS AMO function definitions this ought to work.

Comment: Thanks Meff, I will get back as soon as I get a chance to try this out.  SO doens't respect holidays.

Comment: Thank you Meff, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. You cannot cast the Binding into a QueryBinding, and even if you could (or if you create a new QueryBinding), it generates the wrong XMLA. It generates a Binding element, whereas we need a DataSourceView as in http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4.