# AMO OLAP QueryBinding

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssas

Depending on business logic sometimes I need to change source table for my Customer dimension in Cube.

Previously I was changing structure of cube using the following code:

```
    MyServerDataSourceView.Schema.Tables["DimCustomers"].ExtendedProperties["QueryDefinition"] = "new query";
    MyServerDataSourceView.Update(); // update to new definition
    DimCustomer.Process(ProcessType.ProcessAdd, EF);
    MyServerDataSourceView.Schema.Tables["DimCustomers"].ExtendedProperties["QueryDefinition"] = "old regularquery";
    MyServerDataSourceView.Update(); // revert back to old definition
```

But it is not trustful. Sometimes it doesn't revert back query definition.

Visual Studio shows that there is possibility to use **queryBinding**.
[image]

I was trying such code:

```
string queryAdd = "SELECT [a],[b],[c] FROM ase.newtable";

QueryBinding queryBinding = new QueryBinding();
queryBinding.QueryDefinition = queryAdd;
DimCustomer.Process(ProcessType.ProcessAdd, queryBinding);
```

And get the following error which doesn't say much:

> Warning: 0x80019002 at ProcessAdd Customer Dimension - Sequence
>   Container: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.   The
>   Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1)
>   reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure.  This occurs
>   when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
>   MaximumErrorCount.  Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

I was trying to study [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/analysis-management-objects/programming-amo-olap-basic-objects?view=sql-server-2017) but haven't found there any examples or clear explanation.

Comment: Check if the error has an `InnerException` or `Errors` collection that tells you more. What you're getting there is the outermost error that summarizes the whole operation; there's more details buried in there somewhere. If all else fails, you can use SQL Profiler to capture the command AMO is executing, and execute it yourself to see why it's failing. For advanced scenarios, you may even find it more convenient to construct the XMLA directly and execute it, rather than relying on the black box of AMO.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for comment and for reminding about profiler. Could you propose how to correctly construct XMLA and execute it please?

Comment: The easiest way is actually to have Management Studio generate the statements for you, by performing whatever operation you were planning on the cube and then using the "Script" button rather than actually execute the statement. You can then use `XElement` to mimic this structure. Although you can construct XMLA from scratch with sufficiently diligent study of the documentation, it's a lot of work since it's pretty verbose (`<Batch xmlns=...><Process><Object>...</Object><Type>ProcessAdd</Type>...`, all with the correct namespace). AMO is definitely more convenient, when it works.

Comment: Add a try catch block then a breakpoint. Execute the package and wait for the code to pop up and breakpoint to be hit. Then step through the code and see what error you get. You haven't found the proper error message yet.

Comment: @gregGalloway yes exactly, but I am not even sure that this is correct way of doing the thing. Can't find anything similar on the web. On your blog I read an article about using XMLA ... but not sure how to do it correctly

Comment: @GregGalloway there is one XMLA file (15k rows) for all dimensions in my Data SOurce View folder. So how do I change it and run it only for one dimension from C#

Comment: I also have encountered similar problems with SSAS. Dynamically changing the source doesn’t seem to work very reliably. However, over years of doing this kind of work I have come to the conclusion that you are better off doing the work in the data warehouse (see Kimball), and keeping logic in the cube to a minimum. This helps with with performance for large datasets and allows you to troubleshoot against the warehouse using SQL.